# Tag by Chargeback or Costcenter

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using C# .NET 6 (Core version)
I have multiple customer for my app that uses Twilio for sending SMS.
Is there a way to tag by CustomerID for each SMS sent so that I can chargeback to customer based on usage ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a customer specific URL query parameter when you set the statusCallback when calling the /Messages resource.